# Azure: storage transaction cost

Tags: azure, transactions, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I want to implement a search engine site using Azure platform.

The application will parse from external sites **10.000.000 entry in a day** and need to persist this data. I need about 40GB of repository space.

According to Azure price model it seems that should be better to use **Azure Table Storage** instead of Azure SQL Server. But I'm afraid about the cost of **storage transactions**: 0.01$ for 10.000 transaction.

In my case it will be for a single day: (0.01$ * 10.000.000) / 10.000 = 10$/day = **300$/month**! It seems too much!

Maybe I misunderstood something? If this is true, why should I choose cloud platform? Prices are terrific!

Thanks

Comment: 300 USD per month for 10 million transactions a day sounds cheap to me!

Comment: if you buy a traditional hosting server you'll spend 50 USD per month

Comment: Are you really wanting to move 40GB per day and store that in table storage.  Tell us a bit more about what you are trying to achieve and I will try and help.

Comment: I would like to transfer every day updated info taken from various sites (it's a hotel-like search engine). I've estimated about 10.000.000 of hotels to search, probably changing over time.

Answer (score 3):

A few thoughts:

From a transaction standpoint, there are ways to optimize, such as writing multiple entities within a given partition at once, which can reduce your transaction rate depending on how many you can batch together in a single write.

Also, consider using a map/reduce implementation. This will be an exercise for you to explore further, as we really don't know your schema or viability of map/reduce with your data. That said, it could save you transactions.

Next: SQL Azure, at 40GB, would run about $400 / month. Your solution might fit better with a relational store, depending on searching needs, and pricing isn't that much different (and with no transaction costs).

Finally: Instead of focusing on your storage and transactional cost alone, look at the big picture, and what you're getting (durable, replicated storage; ability to scale to 100TB per account, etc.). And think about your business model, and what it would cost to purchase your own servers (or what it would cost for dedicated hosting). As others have already stated, it's unlikely you'll get the performance you're looking for in a *traditional* hosting offering, since the low-price systems are shared systems with no SLA.

Answer (score 0):

> if you buy a traditional hosting server you'll spend 50 USD per month

I'm not sure a webhosting company would let you do 10 million transactions a day at 50 USD, really.
Anyway if one is crazy to say yes at this price, why don't you go for it and forget about Azure ?

300 USD per month for 10 million transactions a day sounds totally cheap, David is right.